# 30 Min Time Increments not working in Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, calendar

I am having issues getting my code to work. I am trying to create 30 minutes slots in Swift, but it seems to randomly jump an hour every so often. See code below:

```
                    let calendar = Calendar.current
                    var hour = 07
                    var hour2 = 07
                    var minute = 0
                    var timeLoop = 1

                    var startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                    var endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour2, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)


                    repeat {

                        if(timeLoop % 2 == 0){
                            startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour2, minute: 30, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                            endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                        }
                        else {
                            startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour2, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                            endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour2, minute: 30, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                        }

                        if (timeLoop == 1) {
                            startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                            endDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 30, second: 0, of: editedDate)
                        }


                        let eventDate = EventDate()
                        eventDate.startDate = startDate!
                        eventDate.endDate = endDate!
                        self.suggestedDates.append(eventDate)
                        self.suggestedDates.sort(by: {$0.startDate < $1.startDate}) //Recheck this

                        //Only need to add this once for day purposes
                        if (hour == 07) {
                            self.allDayDates.append(eventDate)
                            self.allDayDates.sort(by: {$0.startDate < $1.startDate}) //Recheck this
                        }

                            //update hours
                            hour2 = hour
                            hour += 1
                            timeLoop += 1


                    } while hour <= 21
```

This gives the following results
07:00 - 07:30,
07:30 - 08:00,
08:00 - 08:30,
09:30 - 10:00,
10:00 - 10:30,
11:30 - 12:00,
12:00 - 12:30,
13:30 - 14:00,

As you can see theres a jump from 10:30 to 11:30.

Comment: What you really want to do ?

Comment: I am literally trying to have half an hour slots. But at the moment it's not every half an hour.

Comment: for today, or for given dates array ?

Comment: After a date has been selected, it then creates timeslots automatically every half an hour for the chosen day - hence editedDate

Comment: Perhaps you get a solution more quickly if you edit your question to first shortly describe what you have and what you need; this code seems like an overly complex algorithm to do something very simple.

Comment: for all 24 hours ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not give enough idea of what you are trying to do.

However to get the time slots you can do something like this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let startHour = 07 // Hour from where you want to start the slots
var hourCounter = 07 // Hour counter for looping
let slotDuration = 30 // Constant for duration of slots

let editedDate = Date() // The selected date, as per your code

// Create the start date by setting hour value to the `startHour` of `editedDate`
var startDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: startHour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: editedDate)
// Assign the same value to endDate as the initial value
var endDate = startDate

repeat {

    // Assign the end date to the start date,
    // This will get you the slot start duration from earlier slot's end date
    // For example,
    // If this is the starting slot,
    // then the startDate and endDate will be same, as per above code.
    // If this is any subsequent slot,
    // then the slot should start from the last slot's endDate.
    // i.e. if previous slot was 01:30 - 2:00,
    // then current slot should start from 2:00.
    startDate = endDate

    if let date = startDate {
        // Get the new endDate by adding your slot duration to the startDate
        endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: slotDuration, to: date)
    }

    // ...
    // Do whatever you want to do with these slot values here...
    // ...

    // Increment the counter for looping
    hourCounter += 1

} while hourCounter <= 21
```

The code generates time slots based on the slot duration. You can change the `slotDuration` to any desired value (in minute), and it will generate slots accordingly. Try changing it from 30 to 15 and see the results.